# Slash before InetAddress.getByName(host)

Tags: java, networking

How do I remove the slash  in the output of `InetAddress.getbyName`?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone, I just did it.

One of the solutions is:

```
String ip_old = myInetaddress.toString(); 
String ip_new = ip_old.substring(1);
```

Comment: That solution you now use is a bad hack. Please use the getHostAddress() function to retrieve what you want.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you just want the IP, use the host address:

```
String address = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").getHostAddress();
```

If you just want the host name, use

```
String hostname = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").getHostName();
```

### Edit

The slash you're seeing is probably when you do an implicit `toString()` on the returned `InetAddress` as you try to print it out, which prints the host name and address delimited by a slash (e.g. `stackoverflow.com/64.34.119.12`).  You could use

```
String address = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").toString().split("/")[1];
String hostname = InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com").toString().split("/")[0];
```

But there is no reason at all to go to a `String` intermediary here.  `InetAddress` keeps the two fields separate intrinsically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are doing a toString after this? Why don't you just use normal String manipulation, meaning substring?

Comment: yes! just did it. Thanks!
code-
String ip_old=myInetaddress.toString();
String ip_new=ip_old.substring(1);

Comment: @P Ramesh: That's a really terrible solution since you're going to a String and back for absolutely no reason.  The `InetAddress` already keeps the host name and address separately internally, you just have to ask it for the address like in my answer.  Can you explain why you don't want to use the logical way?